# How to take integers from user as long as user enters?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, integer, cin

I was working on a school project with my friend and we want our program to take integer values from user and store it in a vector as long as the user enter some value and exit the loop for input when user stops inputting numbers.

This was my first sample code which goes on infinitely:

```
while(cin>>x){
                v.push_back(x);
        }
```

There is a condition that the numbers must be greater than one but enter is greater than 0 in integer value so my second code is but it is not working and it also goes on infinitely.

This is my sample code:

```
while(cin>>x){
            if(x<0){
                break;
            }
            else{
                v.push_back(x);
            }
        }
```

Kindly suggest me a solution thanks in advance :)

Comment: What constitutes the end of the user's input?

Comment: When user stops entering numbers and press enter.

Comment: And how are you going to guess that uses will not enter any more items after he pressed enter?

Comment: I want to accept all numbers that user enters.

Comment: That's the problem, can i use getline with integers?

Comment: First ask the user to enter the amount of items he is going to enter.

Comment: The amount is unspecified that is the problem.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: *"... the numbers must be greater than one but enter is greater than 0..."* - deciphering that it *sounds* like you're saying accept input so long as the value entered is greater than zero. if that is the case, then `if(x<0)`is *wrong*, as it only tests for values *less* than zero. Integers strictly greater than zero would break when `if (x <= 0) break;` were true. And in fact, the contrapositive be tested as part of the while condition: `while (std::cin >> x && x > 0) v.push_back(x);`

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct but even it won't break the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important part for you is to clearly describe what you want. The program has to have some condition under which it terminates.

Two ideas:

1. The user enters integer values separated by spaces and then pushes enter
2. The user enters an integer, presses enter and continues. As soon as he presses enter twice, it terminates.

How to do it:

1. Simple use cin with a string, delimit by space and then convert to integers.
2. Use cin with a string but otherwise as you do right now, ask whether the string is "", if not convert to integer.

Comment: Yup i would like to do something like the first idea.

Comment: You still need something? You'll surely find code for delimiting if you search for it. `atoi` does the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but I think you mean something like read the line then extract integers? If so, try something like this - there is no error checking, it will simply discard the everything from the first non-integer. I have left out exceptions and not used and for_each or lambdas or anything fancy. Hopefully will be useful to get you started.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>



std::vector<int> getUserInput(){
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::istringstream is(s);
    while(is){
        int value;
        is >> value;
        if(is) result.push_back(value);
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int,char**){
    std::vector<int> userValues = getUserInput();
    std::cout << "User input values:\n";
    for(int value : userValues) std::cout << value << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After using [Aziuth's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5114342/aziuth)  suggestion and doing some research on websites like Topcoder and Codechef and other competitive programming websites I think i found a solution without needing to use a string. It takes all the input values until a newline is entered. Thanks a lot everyone for their time and knowledge for this question.

The code is:

```
while(1){
            cin>>x;
            v.push_back(x);
            char ch = getchar();
            if(ch=='\n')
                break;
        }
```